# Hierarchical Dendrogram using both continuous and categorical data

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

So i have a  data set that has 90 or so specimens each with the clade they belong to and 5 data points calculated from the length of the line (which is not important here). My aim is to create a dendrogram that essentially calculates the dissimilarity and displays it as a graph, however I want to make it so that the code will separate the specimens by their respective clades into their own clusters then look at how similar/dissimilar they are, but I'm not too sure how to approach this. I'm willing to use any of the available r tools to do so so would appreciate some help. A short example of the data set will be formatted below in the form of a table.

| Name | Type | lenght_1 | length_2 | length_3 | length_4 | length_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spec1 | S | 10 | -15 | -5 | 5 | 10 |
| spec2 | O | 20 | 6 | 6 | -5 | -10 |
| spec3 | O | 22 | 7 | 10 | -3 | -7 |
| spec4 | S | 6 | 6 | -10 | -5 | 3 |
| spec5 | T | 54 | -20 | -20 | 9 | 9 |
| spec5 | T | 25 | -20 | -10 | 5 | 9 |

this is a table that's been made up on the spot but represents what my data generally look like. The type refers the the clade, and the lengths have been calculated by splitting segmented graphs with breaks into 5 sections and finding the average hypotenuse of each line segment. I'd like to determine how similar these lines are for each species in their respective clades (grouping S with other S's and looking at the dissimilarity). Also is there a way to use these dendrograms to perhaps convert the data and draw up a phylogeny (this is just an additional question and does not need to be answered if unknown). thankyou for reading through this my r coding is still progressing hence why these question may seem elementary to some.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be about hierarchical clustering of groups defined by a categorical variable, not hierarchical clustering of both continuous and categorical data. Hierarchical clustering involves a series of decisions about how to scale the data, how to compute distances, and how to create clusters based on those differences so this example will use the default options. Using the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
data(iris)
iris.sub <- iris[c(1:15, 51:65, 101:115), ]
str(iris.sub)
# 'data.frame': 45 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The data consist of 4 measurements on three different species of iris. We'll use 15 of each species for the example. Now we will scale the data by converting to Z-scores so that larger measurements are not more influential than smaller ones and compute the species means:

```
iris.z <- scale(iris.sub[ , 1:4])
iris.agg <- aggregate(iris.z, list(iris.sub$Species), mean)
iris.agg
#      Group.1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     setosa   -0.9871973   0.7967458   -1.2887187  -1.2543022
# 2 versicolor    0.2171329  -0.5487521    0.2754513   0.1735865
# 3  virginica    0.7700644  -0.2479937    1.0132674   1.0807157
```

Next the distances between the means:

```
iris.gdst <- dist(iris.agg[, -1])
iris.gdst
#          1        2
# 2 2.783212         
# 3 3.864052 1.327948
```

Finally the cluster analysis and the dendrogram:

```
iris.hcl <- hclust(iris.gdst, members=table(iris.sub$Species))
plot(iris.hcl, labels=iris.agg$Group.1)
```

For details on the various functions, read the manual pages `?scale`, `?aggregate`, `?dist`, and `?hclust`.

[image: Dendrogram]

You can compute the dendrogram for all of the numeric variables and label the result by species as follows:

```
iris.dst <- dist(iris.z)
iris.all.hcl <- hclust(iris.dst)
plot(iris.all.hcl, labels=iris.sub$Species)
rect.hclust(iris.hcl.all, 3)
```

Notice that setosa is well separated but not versicolor and virginica.

[image: Dendrogram 2]

If we code setosa, versicolor, and virginica as -2, 0, 2 and add it to the distance matrix:

```
iris.sp.dst <- dist(cbind(iris.z, 2*(as.numeric(iris.sub$Species) - 2)))
iris.sp.hcl <- hclust(iris.sp.dst)
plot(iris.sp.hcl, labels=iris.sub$Species)
rect.hclust(iris.sp.hcl, 3)
```

Notice that virginica and versicolor are still intermixed.

[image: Dendrogram 3]

If we arbitrarily increase the range of species to -3, 0, +3 then the species will be separated, but this is just because we increased the magnitude of the species variable.

Comment: this was really helpful i can see the similarity/dissimilarity between groups but if i wanted to see the individuals specimens would i have to perform the clustering's again for each species. so in this case id do a dendrogram for all versicolor, virginica and setosa? Im looking to do the clustering defined by both categorical and continuous data.

Comment: See the expanded answer for the details, adding a categorical variable makes little difference or all the difference depending on how you weight the categorical variable(s). If you want to find out which numeric variables help to distinguish different species, use discriminant analysis not cluster analysis.